# Blazor server-side, error handling without forced to reload?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a server-side blazor app and whenever an error occurs i am forced to reload the page. Is there any good ways of redirecting the user to a custom made error page instead of the yellow bar that appears at the bottom of the page?

You cant navigate to other pages before reloading and this is very annoying for users...

Answer (score 0):

My best answer to you would be to guard for your exceptions. Make some sort of try/catch blocks when you encounter places where exceptions might happen and handle them in your frontend in stead of letting the application throw an exception. If you do this the application is not forced to stop and therefore a user is not forced to reload their page.

```cs
try {
    // Some code to send data to a database via a service or controller
} catch (ArgumentException e) when (e.ParamName == "Stiffler's Mom")
{
    // Some code to redirect the user/show validation errors, if something is wrong
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **ErrorBoundary** you can create your own component for the information about error that the user will see on the client-side.
Simple example for razor page(***.razor**):

```
<ErrorBoundary @ref=errorBoundary>
   <ChildContent>
        @*---Here is your component or page---*@
   </ChildContent>
   <ErrorContent>
        @*---Here is your own component for displaying error---*@
   <ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>


@code{
    private ExErrorBoundary? errorBoundary;
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
         errorBoundary?.Recover();
    }
}
```

The **Recover()** is necessary to reset **ErrorBoundary** during subsequent navigation.

Detailed description here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#error-boundaries

If you want to get information about the **exception** that caused **ErrorBoundary**, then you need to inherit the class from **ErrorBoundary** and get the **CurrentException** property like shown below:

```
public class ExErrorBoundary : ErrorBoundary
{
     public new Exception? CurrentException => base.CurrentException;
}
```